# Use mixedsort on a select group of cells, R

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop, dataframe, apply

I have a `data.frame` of cells containing a mix of numbers and characters. 
For example

```
data(iris)

iris$comb<-paste(iris$Sepal.Length,'-',iris$Species)

iris$comb2<-paste(iris$Sepal.Width,'-',iris$Species)

head(iris[,6:7])

  comb        comb2
1 5.1 - setosa 3.5 - setosa
2 4.9 - setosa   3 - setosa
3 4.7 - setosa 3.2 - setosa
4 4.6 - setosa 3.1 - setosa
5   5 - setosa 3.6 - setosa
6 5.4 - setosa 3.9 - setosa
```

I want to sort groups of cells based on their numeric value, and I can do this with `gtools::mixedsort()`. However, I have several columns that need this, and I only want to sort every 3 rows in a column, independently of the rest of the column. The (extremely) long way to do this would be

```
library(gtools)

mixedsort(iris[1:3,6],decreasing=TRUE)
mixedsort(iris[4:6,6],decreasing=TRUE)
```

I'm just not sure how to loop through little bunches of cells like this. I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a grouping variable using `gl` and then using `mutate_at` specify the columns of interest to apply the function

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     group_by(grp =  as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(matches("comb")), funs(mixedsort(., decreasing = TRUE))) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     select(-grp)
```

Comment: you have answered quite a few of my questions and I see 'quite a few' questions in general. I really appreciate your efforts. Thanks!